# Cancelling a ngResource query only cancels OPTIONS request

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have an angular resource that sends a query to an API. All resourceProviders have cancelRequest enabled:

```
.config(function($resourceProvider) {
    $resourceProvider.defaults.cancellable = true;
});
```

When I make a request, such as:

```
myProviderAPI.Persons.query(blah blah);
```

I'm able to call:

```
myProviderAPI.Persons.query().$cancelRequest();
```

I think this is working (ie. it isn't erroring), but it is actually only cancelling the OPTIONS request, but not the actual GET request. This is in Chrome but is a blocker. I need it to actually cancel the GET request. FWIW, here's the pertinent doc info from Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). I'm running Angular 1.5.0